# Android Studio - not asking Write_External_Storage

Tags: java, android

[image]

[image]

How I'm requesting

```
 public void requestPermissionToWriteToFile() {

 if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Permission needed")
                    .setMessage("This permission is needed for camera use and internal file save")
                    .setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                    PERMISSION_REQUEST_WRITE_FILES);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }).create().show();
    }
    else
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        PERMISSION_REQUEST_WRITE_FILES);
    }
}
```

How I'm Checking

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if(requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_WRITE_FILES){
        if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {Toast.makeText(this, "PERMISSION_GRANTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
        else
        {Toast.makeText(this, "PERMISSION_DENIED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
    }
}
```

As soon as the app boots up, the accesses is never granted and it just stays that way, when I call on the above method the dialog for permission wont come up (the permission isn't being asked). Even when I go to settings and change it from there it still won't grant me permission to WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. the above code is in my main class, the permission is in Manifest, what else is needed to fix this?

- there was another thread like this but that didn't solve my problem jsyk.

Comment: There's no way for us to verify that you're actually calling `requestPermissionToWriteToFile`

Comment: Also, you have a typo in your manifest. You're missing the G in STORAGE.

Comment: I tried your code and it works, you need to call requestPermissionToWriteToFile inside the onCreate method.

Comment: it indeed was the 'G' I'm sorry to have wasted your time. that was fully my bad. every thing works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before trying the following code, add the missing G in STORAGE.

```
<uses-permission    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Then call this when your button is clicked:

```
if (androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == android.content.pm.PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED || androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == android.content.pm.PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {

androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[] {android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1001);
} else {
//permission already granted
}
```

Also, add read external storage permission to avoid any issues:

```
<uses-permission    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: omg! first of all nice spotting. I didn't see the 'G' mistake, that was the issue. all good now thankyou very much @Ilyasse Salama